# What are Ruby globals useful for?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

Why does Ruby have global variables like `$$` at all?

Couldn't similar behavior be obtained by defining accessors and attributes in `Kernel` ?

Is this to prevent overriding in subclasses ?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the [special globals](http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html) like `$$` etc or about global variables generally? The special globals are one of the influences in Ruby that come from Perl and indeed there are alternative methods to obtain the same information (`Process.id` in the case of `$$`), which would be preferred these days.

Comment: Globals generally, although the existence of $$, $0 etc would seem to sanction their usage.

Comment: Yes, similar behavior could be obtained by defining methods (accessors) on Kernel, but "similar," to state the obvious, is not "same." For one thing, method calls are expensive in Ruby, at least compared to accessing a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has multiple parts and therefore answers.

Q1.

> Why does Ruby have global variables like $$ at all?

Ruby borrows from Perl and LISP.  Both have global variables.

> Ruby inherited the Perl philosophy of having more than one way to do
>   the same thing.   *Yukihiro Matsumoto - September 29, 2003*

Q2.

> Couldn't similar behavior be obtained by defining accessors
>   and attributes in Kernel ?

Yes, and they have been.  However it can be held that there exist programmed values that have global applicability and therefore should have global scope without introducing any intermediary code.

While it might be more OO to encapsulate these inside a class method the question then becomes which is more important to the user, simplicity or style.  The name of the script file passed to the virtual machine is an invariant.  As are the command line arguments.  There is little benefit obtained by abstracting access to those value through a method.  A global variable is sufficient for the purpose and is as lightweight as is possible to achieve.

Q3.

> Is this to prevent overriding in subclasses ?

The answer to this is unknown to me.

Finally, we come to what is the Question asked in the title:

> What are Ruby globals useful for?

One can trace variable assignments in Ruby via the `trace_var` Kernel method:

```
trace_var :$_, proc {|v| puts "$_ is now '#{v}'" }
$_ = "hello"
$_ = ' there'
```

Outputs to STDOUT:

```
$_ is now 'hello'
$_ is now ' there'
```

One can conceive of an application which has some event driven change to a variable named $state, say a GUI or sensor feed, where simply tracing changes to global variables eliminates the need for program code implementing essentially the same feature.